# NHibernate refusing to Refresh an object

Tags: nhibernate

We are running webservices which get called to populate and update our database, in one of the functions an EntityReactionType get's filled by the caller of the webservice with the ID's.

EntityReactionType has a composite many-to-one key consisting of Entity and (suprise) ReactionType.

These ID's get filled with the right values and i then want to refresh the object from the database in order to check some values which are set in the database but the user has no knowledge of. In this case: IsStart and IsClosing.

I do all this with the following code: (it's a simplified snipped but the idea should be clear)

I can see the refresh executing the SQL, which is correct and shows that this has IsStart = False and IsClosing = True.

Yet when i look at the object values after the Refresh IsStart = null and IsClosing = False;

```
//entityReactionTypeRepository.Merge(reaction.EntityReactionType); 
entityReactionTypeRepository.Refresh(reaction.EntityReactionType);

if (reaction.IsResolved == true || reaction.EntityReactionType.CloseDispute == true)
{
     reaction.IsResolved = true;
     reaction.Invoice.IsDisputed = false;
}
```

I have the Merge line commented out since that is something i found while searching google but changed nothing (idea was that you can't refresh something that isn't transistant but nothing changed, SQL get's executed eitherway but the values do not get updated)

I'm close to making a work around at this time that just creates a detachedcriteria and executes that but i know this should be possible like this.

Greetings,

Folkert

Comment: Can you post the code for the full refresh method?

Comment: That just calls the current Session.Refresh(object)

Comment: How are these values getting set in the database?  Trigger?

Comment: No, they are already there, in whole a user sends in a Reaction with a EntityReactionType, the user knows the ID's needed but does not know any of the other values of an EntityReactionType. I need to refresh the EntityReactionType with the actual values as stored in the database.

Comment: Can you post your classes/mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well today i revisited this problem and i think i understand why it did this, it seems to me when i called the Refresh it kept the original values because in my code before i refresh i also made a Invoice object presistant. The invoice itself doesn't have EntityReactionTypes but in it's object graph it does reference there.

I figure for this reason the session decides to keep the values as they are in the presistent version of the invoice.

So what i did is i put this refresh pretty much at the top of the method and it started to work like it used to and actually pull the values from the database.

Seems odd to me though that it wouldn't change the property values when i did a refresh but this is what it did for me.